# An iterator that doesn't squash references?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I want a for loop in Python that can modify variables in the iterator, not just handle the value of the variables. As a trivial example, the following clearly does not do what I want because b is still a string at the end.

```
a = 3
b = "4"
for x in (a, b):
    x = int(x)
print("b is %s" % type(b))
```

(Result is `"b is a <class 'str'>`")

What is a good design pattern for "make changes to each variable in a long list of variables"?

Comment: One of the responders below made a point I should have made here: this is for Python 3.

Comment: Yes, we can guess it's 3.x, not just because you're using `print` as a function, but because the output says `<class 'str'>` instead of `<type 'str'>` (and you're probably using CPython…), but in general it's worth adding the appropriate 2.7 or 3.x tag if there's any chance it might make a difference, because otherwise half the answers are going to guess wrong and give you code that doesn't work…

Comment: Try to use `format` instead of `%`.

Comment: b is a reference, and as such to reassign it you need to explicitly call `b = something` or access it through `locals()` or such

Comment: @njzk2 Due to the way the generated code access local variables (`LOAD_FAST` opcode -- no dictionary look-up), it is probably not advisable to change a local variable through the `locals` dictionary. EDIT: this is in fact [mentioned in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals): _"The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter."_

Comment: @SylvainLeroux totally agree. I don't think changing the type of a variable is something I would advise either, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: you can't do that.

```
a = "3"
b = "4"
for x in (a, b):
    x = int(x)
```

Variables in Python are only tags that references values. Theres is not such thing as "tags on tags". When you write `x = int(x)` if the above code, you only change what `x` points to. Not the pointed value.

---

> What is a good design pattern for "make changes to each variable in a long list of variables"?

I'm not sure to really understand, but if you want to do things like that, maybe you should store your values not as individual variables, but as value in a dictionary, or as instance variables of an object.

```
my_vars = {'a': "3",
           'b': "4" }
for x in my_vars:
    my_vars[x] = int(my_vars[x])

print type(my_vars['b'])
```

---

Now if you're in the hackish mood:

As your variables are *globals* they are in fact stored as entries in a dictionary (accessible through the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) function). So you could change them:

```
a = "3"
b = "4"
for x in ('a', 'b'):
    globals()[x] = int(globals()[x])

print type(b)
```

But, as of myself, I wouldn't call that *"good design pattern"*...

Comment: If you want to get that hackish, as long as `a` and `b` are not equal, you can use the `frame` object to find out which names match the values and set `globals` that way. (Or inspect the frame's bytecode and/or source…) :)

Comment: @abarnert: if they actually are equal, you probably can manage anyway, just as long as they are not equal to something you don't want to change, I guess

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in another answer, there's no way to update a variable indirectly. The best you can do is assign it explicitly with unpacking:

```
>>> a = 3
>>> b = 4
>>> a, b = [int(x) for x in a, b]
>>> print "b is %s" % type(b)
b is <type 'int'>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an actual list of variables (as opposed to a number of individual variables you want to modify), then a list comprehension will do what you want:

```
>>> my_values = [3, "4"]
>>> my_values = [int(value) for value in my_values]
>>> print(my_values)
[3, 4]
```

If you want to do more complicated processing, you can define a function and use that in the list comprehension:

```
>>> my_values = [3, "4"]
>>> def number_crunching(value):
...     return float(value)**1.42
... 
>>> my_values = [number_crunching(value) for value in my_values]
>>> print(my_values)
[4.758961394052794, 7.160200567423779]
```